# Post with jquery to php handler page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

How to post to php handler page with jquery?

Form index.php POST to some.php.

Note: I don't want to use serialize.

```
$("button").click(function(){
    $.post("some.php",
    {
        name: "Donald Duck",
        city: "Duckburg"
    }
});
```

but it is not redirected to `some.php` when I click.
my simplify code

```
index.php    
<table>
<tr><td><button class="entr">This</button></td></tr>
</table>
```

and

```
some.php
<?php
echo '<pre>';
print_r($_POST);
echo '</pre>';
?>
```

Comment: Check your browser console to get errors and copy & paste here..

Answer (score 0):

Try that,

```
$.post("some.php", {
    "name": "Donald Duck",
    "city": "Duckburg"
}, function(data) {
    // On success.
});
```

Where you see `// On success` you'd put your code there to do whatever you want with the data which is returned from the `PHP` page.

Comment: @Student if it fails, then please post your PHP code too and any console output.

Answer (score 0):

I assume your button is also a link, so when they click it, it's causing the default action, which is to visit the link, so this would prevent that:

```
$("button").click(function(e){ // Make sure to pass the e into the function
    e.preventDefault();  // This will prevent the default browser action, which in your case is a click

    $.post("some.php",
    {
        name: "Donald Duck",
        city: "Duckburg"
    }
});
```

On the other hand, if it isn't going to the page and you want it to, put the button in a form instead of submitting it with jquery.